# Echo series of computed values

Tags: angularjs

Given:

```
<input ng-model="x.costA" value="100" step="any" type="number" />
<input ng-model="x.costB" value="100" step="any" type="number" />
```

I need to take `x.costA` and `x.costB` (whenever the user updates the values) and compute a series of results that will be outputted into a `<div>` somewhere else on the page: Abstractly:

```
<div>
    Result 1: {{ result1 }}
    Result 2: {{ result2 }}
    Result 3: {{ result3 }}
</div>
```

These three different results are computed using the input data, costA and costB.

The computations that need to occur are quite complex so I do not want to place the arithmetic within `{{...}}`. I would rather have it in a Angular Controller/Service (*not sure which*??).

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can put a `$watch` on `x.costA+x.costB` so when they change, all your results are computed. However, since you mentioned the results are complex/expensive, you may want to add a button for the user to click to trigger the computation by the user.

```
<button ng-click="computeNow()">Go!</button>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.computeNow() = function() {
  $scope.result1 = $scope.x.costA + $scope.x.costB;
  // etc.
}
```